# Meta tags are being displayed more than once

Tags: php, html

I created a header.php and footer.php to lessen code repetition. Now the problem i am having is that when i go in Inspect element I see that the head tag which includes the meta tags etc.. are being displayed twice.

I am using the include function in php to display the header.php and footer.php

How can I prevent it from being displayed more than once?

This is my Header.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:image/x-icon;," type="image/x-icon"> 
    <title>El Tabata</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="responsive.css">
    
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
</head>

<body>
    <header class="nav-down">
        <nav class="container navbar">

            <div class="hamburger">
                <span class="bar"></span>
                <span class="bar"></span>
                <span class="bar"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="logo">
                <h1 style="color: white">El Tabata</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="nav-ul nav-center ">
                <ul >
                    <li style="--animation-order: 1;"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                    <li style="--animation-order: 2;"><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
                    <li style="--animation-order: 3;"><a href="people.php">People</a></li>
                    <li style="--animation-order: 4;"><a href="menu.php">Menu</a></li>
                    <li style="--animation-order: 5;"><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
                    <li style="--animation-order: 6;"><a href="reservations.php">Reservations</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="icon">
                <a href="favourites.php"><img src="heart.svg" alt="favorites"></a>
            </div>
                
        </nav>
    </header>
```

This is my Footer.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:image/x-icon;," type="image/x-icon"> 
    <title>El Tabata</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="responsive.css">

    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b3c12f2bf7.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    

</head>

<body>

    <footer>

        <div class=" container footer-dist">
            <div class="footer-left">
                    <img src="./assets/mexican-mascot.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="footer-center">
                    <h3>El Tabata</h3>

                    <p class="footer-links">
                        <a href="index.php">Home</a>
                        |
                        <a href="about.php">About</a>
                        |
                        <a href="people.php">People</a>
                        |
                        <a href="menu.php">Menu</a>
                        |
                        <a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
                        |
                        <a href="reservations.php">Reservations</a>
                    </p>
                            
                    <p class="footer-names">© 2021 | Anthony Mifsud | Leon Zammit | Luke Portanier | CIS1054-SEM2-A-2021</p>
            </div>

            <div class="footer-right">
                <img src="./assets/mexican-mascot.png" alt="">
            </div>
        <div>


   </footer>
```

[image]

Comment: look at your footer.html - it has your header in there. you need to clean that up

Comment: Header and footer are just repetitive sections you want to include in your template files. It makes no sense for either to contain a full HTML structure.

Comment: Header and footer repeat some of the same content, including meta tags...so obviously it appears twice. It's unclear why you are surprised by this. And as noted above, it makes no sense to have it like this at all.

Answer (score 1):

this behavior is normal, you have declared two different web pages, one in the header and one in the footer.
The browser removes the second doctype from the response to respect the W3C standards.

You can create a template.php page which contains the html structure of an HTML document (Doctype and meta tags) and include the header and footer files limited to the content of your body.

index.php or template.php

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Titre de la page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <your meta balise>
</head>
<body>
<?php
  include('header.php')
  inlcude('footer.php')
?>
</body>
</html>
```

header.php

```html
<header class="nav-down">
        <nav class="container navbar">

            <div class="hamburger">
                <span class="bar"></span>
                <span class="bar"></span>
                <span class="bar"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="logo">
                <h1 style="color: white">El Tabata</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="nav-ul nav-center ">
                <ul >
                    <li style="--animation-order: 1;"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                    <li style="--animation-order: 2;"><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
                    <li style="--animation-order: 3;"><a href="people.php">People</a></li>
                    <li style="--animation-order: 4;"><a href="menu.php">Menu</a></li>
                    <li style="--animation-order: 5;"><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
                    <li style="--animation-order: 6;"><a href="reservations.php">Reservations</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="icon">
                <a href="favourites.php"><img src="heart.svg" alt="favorites"></a>
            </div>
                
        </nav>
    </header>
```

footer.php

```html
<footer>

        <div class=" container footer-dist">
            <div class="footer-left">
                    <img src="./assets/mexican-mascot.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="footer-center">
                    <h3>El Tabata</h3>

                    <p class="footer-links">
                        <a href="index.php">Home</a>
                        |
                        <a href="about.php">About</a>
                        |
                        <a href="people.php">People</a>
                        |
                        <a href="menu.php">Menu</a>
                        |
                        <a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
                        |
                        <a href="reservations.php">Reservations</a>
                    </p>
                            
                    <p class="footer-names">© 2021 | Anthony Mifsud | Leon Zammit | Luke Portanier | CIS1054-SEM2-A-2021</p>
            </div>

            <div class="footer-right">
                <img src="./assets/mexican-mascot.png" alt="">
            </div>
        <div>


   </footer>
```

Hope it was usefull to you